# How to resolve "Too many levels of symbolic links" on my Documents folder?

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems, symlink, deepin

I am using the latest Deepin 15.11 and have just discovered that I cannot access my Documents folder (/home/username/Documents). In my file manager (Deepin File Manager) it simply says "You do not have permission to access this folder."

When I try to navigate there via my terminal I get this:

```
bash: cd: Documents: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

So I did a little digging and discovered that the output of `find -L ./ -mindepth 15` is as follows:

```
find: ‘./Documents’: Too many levels of symbolic links
find: ‘./Templates’: Too many levels of symbolic links
find: ‘./Public’: Too many levels of symbolic links
find: File system loop detected; ‘./.steam/root’ is part of the same file system loop as ‘./.steam’.
```

Which seems to point to some other underlying symlink/permission issue. Attempting to change the ownership of the folder back to my username also fails due to the same "too many levels of symbolic links" error.

This is a fairly fresh install and I haven't done anything I would imagine could cause something like this.

Does anyone know how to resolve this without losing what was in my Documents folder? (assuming it's not already gone)

Comment: That `find` command is not producing any good output.  Please try running `find /home/$username -type l -exec ls -l {} \;` and post the result in your question to show all of the symbolic links.

Comment: The output of the command you provided was: lrwxrwxrwx 1 sonar sonar 21 Nov 21 06:03 /home/sonar/Documents -> /home/sonar/Documents (sonar being my username)

Comment: That is a bad symbolic link, as it points to itself.  You seem to have no Documents directory.

Comment: Is there any chance it was just somehow linked to itself, and that the symlink could be removed? If not, how do I just get rid of it and create a fresh Documents folder? Removing the directory doesn't work.

Comment: You are not showing what you are trying, just stating "it doesn't work" does not give anyone useful information to attempt to help you.  To remove the symbolic link, try `unlink /home/sonar/Documents`.  You should not have been able to create that symbolic link if there was an actual `Documents` directory there.  Did you check that maybe you renamed the `Documents` directory to something else or maybe put it in a different directory?  `find / -type d -name *Documents*` could help.

Comment: Using `unlink Documents` worked, and for some reason the directory was still there. Sorry about the unhelpful message, and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

It was suggested that I run `find /home/$username/Documents -type l -exec ls -l {} \;` which provided this output: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 sonar sonar 18 Nov 21 06:03 /home/$username/Documents -> /home/$username/Documents`

Turns out the Documents folder was symlinked to itself. Running `unlink Documents` completely resolved the issue and allowed me to access my Documents folder again with no issue. Thanks GracefulRestart!

Comment: I wonder how it could had happened. Anyone has an idea?